# Simpler way to transform a DOMSource into a StreamSource?

Tags: java, xml, dom, transform

I need to transform a `DOMSource` into a `StreamSource`, because a third-party library only accepts stream sources for SOAP.

Performance is not so much of an issue in this case, so I came up with this horribly verbose set of commands:

```
DOMSource src = new DOMSource(document);
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
result.setOutputStream(out);
transformer.transform(src, result);
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(in);
```

Isn't there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is as good a way as any. Because your third party library only accepts XML in lexical form, you have no alternative but to serialize the DOM so that the external library can re-parse it. Stupid design - tell them so.

Comment: "Them"? You mean both Apache and Weblogic? :-) The funny thing is, the method signature accepts any `Source`, but the decompiled implementation quietly rejects everything but `StreamSource`...